# How do I configure transactions with Solr and myBatis in Spring (Java)?

Tags: solr, transactions, mybatis, jta

I have a Java Spring 3.0 application that inserts data in a database via myBatis 3.1 and also uses DataImportHandler (DIH) to have Solr 3.6.1 index that database data as well as index binary file attachments. So, I would like to have transaction that rollback changes if any of the following fail:

1) 3 inserts into the database using myBatis

2) solr DIH index of the 3 inserts

3) solr index of binary files

I'm guessing that I need to use JTA since I have multiple datasources but I do not know how to configure with Solr in the mix. How can this be done? Any online references that demonstrate how to accomplish this would also be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked a Similar Solr transaction management question before.  The below links would be helpful.

[solr transaction management using solrj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805117/solr-transaction-management-using-solrj)

[SolrJ Thread Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371101/solrj-thread-safety/6737063#6737063)

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you could also try to replace the DIH updates to the index using `HttpSolrServer` so that you can make use of springs `TransactionSynchronizationManager`

```
if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) {
  TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
    //... 
  });
}
```